# Issues with implementing strstr in NASM

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I've been struggling with implementing the following *strstr* function in NASM:

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    size_t n = strlen(s2);
    while(*s1)
        if(!memcmp(s1++,s2,n))
            return s1-1;
    return 0;
}
```

So far I have the following code:

```
global _mystrstr
extern _strlen
extern _memcmp
_mystrstr:

    ; prologue goes here

    ; moving s1 to edi and s2 to esi    
    ; pushing n onto the stack and jumping to the loop

    ; while(*s1)
    .while_loop:
        cmp     byte[edi], 0
        je      .return_null
        ; memcmp(s1++,s2,n)
        push    dword[esp + 4]
        push    esi
        push    edi
        call    _memcmp
        add     esp, 12
        inc     edi
        ; if(!memcmp(s1++,s2,n))
        cmp     eax, 0
        jne     .while_loop
        jmp     .return_value

    .return_value:
        ; blah blah

    .return_null:
        ; standard stuff goes here
```

For some reason *memcmp* never returns 0. I've tested it with *printf* by printing out the values that eax holds, and it's always either 1 or -1. Could anyone point out what I could possibly be doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you looking for `n` at the right address? What's exactly the behaviour of `push eax`?

Comment: This can read outside `s1` (and potentially segfault) if `s2` is much longer than `s1`, unless `memcmp` always goes in increasing order and never reads any bytes past where a `'\0'` in `s1` doesn't match something else in `s2`.  A vectorized `memcpy` that uses unaligned loads of 16B chunks or something can easily read past the end of `s1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After pushing `eax` on the stack, `esp` points to that memory location. The line

```
push    dword[esp + 4]
```

will not `push` the value of `n` but the value pushed beforehand.
Replace the line with

```
push dword[esp]
```

and try again.